# RSolve: Errors while solving Partial Difference Equation

Tags: difference-equations

I tried solving following partial difference equation in *Mathematica* by typing

```
RSolve[{C[n, k] == C[n-1, k] + C[n-1, k-1], C[n, 0] == 1, C[n, n] == 1}, C[n, k], {n, k}]
```

but returns the following error message

> RSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently. >>

but it does not work, please someone help me in this regard. Thanks and regards in advance.

Comment: And when it failed it did not got you thinking ... ?

Comment: @Sektor Do you imply that there is a trivial error? I fail to see it, could you please be more specific?

Comment: @IstvánZachar No, imply that he ran into some kind of trouble and the first thing to do is: Help me !

Comment: @IstvánZachar `C[n, n] == 1` isn't an init.cond nor a rec.rel.

Comment: @belisarius Yes, but the error message doesn't really help to figure out the conceptual error, does it?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Conceptual. That's the key :) Are you implying that this is a mathematics- rather than a *Mathematica*-related problem :) ?

Comment: @IstvánZachar To me, most Mma errors (including this one) sound more like an invitation to exegesis.

Comment: In[1]: RSolve[{C[n, k] == C[n - 1, k] + C[n - 1, k - 1], C[1, 0] == 1, 
  C[1, 1] == 1}, C[n, k], {n, k}]
Out[1]: RSolve[{C[n, k] == C[-1 + n, -1 + k] + C[-1 + n, k], C[1, 0] == 1, 
  C[1, 1] == 1}, C[n, k], {n, k}]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Mathematica's `RSolve[]` simply can't solve this rather simple type of partial recurrence. However, the problem itself can easily be solved completely with Mathematica as follows. This is also a hint to try alternative formulations in mathematica if a specific one does not succeed. See [Why does Mathematica not evaluate the difference recurrence using `RSolve` or `RecurrenceTable`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86533/why-does-mathematica-not-evaluate-the-difference-recurrence-using-rsolve-or-r/86564#86564) for a similar problem and its solution.

As a first step to solve the given recurrence we rewrite the recurrence relations as function definitions (henceforth writing `a[n,k]` instead of `C[n,k]` because `C` is a reserved symbol in Mathematica)

```
Clear[a]
a[n_, k_] := a[n, k] = a[n - 1, k] + a[n - 1, k - 1]
a[n_, n_] := a[n, n] = 1
a[n_, 0] := a[n, 0] = 1
```

The first few `a[n,k`] are then

```
nn = 10;
t = Table[a[n, k], {n, 0, nn}, {k, 0, n}]

(*
Out[217]= {
{1}, 
{1, 1}, 
{1, 2, 1}, 
{1, 3, 3, 1}, 
{1, 4, 6, 4, 1}, 
{1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1}, 
{1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1}, 
{1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1}, 
{1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1}, 
{1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1}, 
{1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1}}
*)
```

Now we proceed to find the general formula for the elements. We could guess it immediately from the numbers obtained to be a binomial coefficient. But let us proceed differently.

The generating function of the `a[n,k]` is easily found to be

```
Clear[g]

g[x_, y_] := 1/(1 - (x +  x y))
```

In fact the coefficients of the series expansion of `g`, given by

```
Clear[b]

b[n_, k_] := 1/(n! k!) D[g[x, y], {x, n}, {y, k}] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
```

are identical to `a[n,k]` as can be seen from the first few values.

Expansion of `g` in a geometrical series and using the binomial theorem leads to the explicit formula for the solution of the recurrence equation:

```
c[n_, k_] := Binomial[n, k]
```

which we probably have already recognized earlier from the numbers.