# Why does Mathematica not evaluate the difference recurrence using `RSolve` or `RecurrenceTable`?

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation, recursion, difference-equations

*Mathematica* does not evaluate the following recurrence of two variables using [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) and only echoes the input:

```
RSolve[{a[m, n] == a[m, n - 1] + a[m - 1, n - 1] + a[m - 1, n], a[1, n] == 1, a[m, 1] == 1}, a[m, n], {m, n}]
```

Then, I settle for [`RecurrenceTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html), and *Mathematica* does not evaluate it either:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[m, n] == a[m, n - 1] + a[m - 1, n - 1] + a[m - 1, n], a[1, n] == 1, a[m, 1] == 1}, a, {m, 1, 3}, {n, 1, 3}] // Grid
```

> ***Problem:*** Why does *Mathematica* not evaluate the recurrence? Maybe *Mathematica* cannot find the closed form for it using `RSolve`, but why does it not evaluate the recurrence using `RecurrenceTable` either?

---

***My Trials:***

If I remove the `a[m, n - 1]` part from the recurrence, it works:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[m, n] == a[m - 1, n - 1] + a[m - 1, n], a[1, n] == 1, a[m, 1] == 1}, a, {m, 1, 3}, {n, 1, 3}] // Grid
(*
   1 1 1
   2 2 2
   4 4 4
*)
```

If I leave `a[m, n - 1]` and remove any one (or both) of the other two parts from the recurrence, it does not work again.

---

In document for [`RecurrenceTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html), there is a similar example:

```
RecurrenceTable[{s1[n, k] == s1[n - 1, k - 1] - (n - 1) s1[n - 1, k], s1[0, k] == KroneckerDelta[k]}, s1, {n, 0, 6}, {k, 0, 4}] // Grid
```

So, I just *guess* that it may be required for the first parameter to be decreased in the recurrence.

---

***Similar Post:*** This [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27193/22068) comes up with the same problem, but it asks for additional ways instead of what is going on here.

Comment: From your initial conditions I get `a[1, 1]=1`; how would I calculate `a[1,2] = a[1, 1]+a[0,1] + a[0, 2]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks `a[1, 2] = 1` according to the initial condition `a[1,n] == 1`. No need to apply the recurrence for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is not an answer to the question as put, the problem can be solved completely with Mathematica as follows. This is also a hint to try alternative formulations in mathematica if a specific one does not succeed. Assuming, of course, that the problem is in the center of interest.

The easiest way to obtain the values of `a[n,m]` is to start with these equations which are just your recurrence relations written as function definitions:

```
a[n_, m_] := a[n, m] = a[n - 1, m] + a[n - 1, m - 1] + a[n, m - 1]

a[1, m_] := a[1, m] = 1

a[n_, 1] := a[n, 1] = 1
```

The first few `a[n,m]` are then

```
nn = 10;
t = Table[a[n, m], {n, 1, nn}, {m, 1, nn}]

(*
Out[104]= {
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}, 
{1, 5, 13, 25, 41, 61, 85, 113, 145, 181}, 
{1, 7, 25, 63, 129, 231, 377, 575, 833, 1159}, 
{1, 9, 41, 129, 321, 681, 1289, 2241, 3649, 5641}, 
{1, 11, 61, 231, 681, 1683, 3653, 7183, 13073, 22363}, 
{1, 13, 85, 377, 1289, 3653, 8989, 19825, 40081, 75517}, 
{1, 15, 113, 575, 2241, 7183, 19825, 48639, 108545, 224143}, 
{1, 17, 145, 833, 3649, 13073, 40081, 108545, 265729, 598417}, 
{1, 19, 181, 1159, 5641, 22363, 75517, 224143, 598417, 1462563}}
*)
```

Now it is easy to show that the generating function is related to

```
g[x_, y_] := 1/(1 - (x + y  + x y))
```

in fact the series coefficients (shiften by 1) of `g` given by

```
b[n_, m_] := 
 1/((m - 1)! (n - 1)!) D[g[x, y], {x, n - 1}, {y, m - 1}] /. {x -> 0, 
   y -> 0}
```

are identical to `a[n,m].`

Expanding the series g using the binomial theorem twice we find an explicit formula for `a[n,m]` in the form

```
c[n_, m_] := 
 Sum[Binomial[k, 2 k - n - m + 2] Binomial[2 k - n - m + 2, k - m + 1], {k, 
   0, \[Infinity]}]
```

It takes some time to evaluate but it is an expilcit formula.

**EDIT #1**

The formulas starting from the generating function can be simplified.
The new names have a number 1 appended.

Generating function

```
g1[x_, y_] := x y /(1 - (x + y  + x y))
```

Coefficients of series expansion (no shift anymore)

```
b1[n_, m_] := 
 1/(m! n!) D[g1[x, y], {x, n}, {y, m}] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
```

Explicit formula of solution (now an explicitly finite sum)

```
c1[n_, m_] := 
 Sum[Binomial[k - 1, 2 k - m - n] Binomial[2 k - m - n, k - m], {k, 
   Min[n, m], n + m - 1}]
```

or, symmetrically, and with explicit visibility of the limits of summation due to 1/r! = 0 if r<0

```
c2[n_, m_] := 
 Sum[(k - 1)!/((n + m - 1 - k)! (n - k)! (m - k)!), {k, Min[n, m], 
   n + m - 1}]
```

Comment: thank you for this instructive answer +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I will not answer the failure of in-built functions but present an alternative approach:

```
f[m_, u_] := With[{r = {{-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, -1}}},
   ReplacePart[m, u -> Total[(Extract[m, u + #1] &) /@ r]]];
sa[m_, n_] := Module[{s, p},
   s = Normal@SparseArray[{{i_, 1} -> 1, {1, j_} -> 1}, {m, n}, "x"];
   p = Position[s, "x"];
   Fold[f[#1, #2] &, s, p]];
vis[m_, n_] := 
  TableForm[sa[m, n], TableHeadings -> {Range[m], Range[n]}];
```

For example, `vis[10,8]`:

[image]